# Definition of multiplicative group of a field in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving, formal-verification

```
theory Scratch
  imports
    "HOL.Fields"
    "HOL.Groups"
begin

locale Field_is_group=
  fixes F :: "'a :: field"
begin
typedef 'a mul_group = "{x :: 'a set. x ≠ 0}"
end

end
```

I'm new to Isabelle, and I have learned something about proving in first-order logic but not about data structures. I tried to formalize the proof of the fact that a field has a multiplicative group, but I don't know how to define the multiplicative group. It is the set of the whole field except zero, and a field in Isabelle is defined as a type. By looking about the references, I know I need use `typedef`, but it fails:

```
Type unification failed: No type arity set :: zero

Failed to meet type constraint:

Term:  λx. x ≠ 0 :: ??'b ⇒ bool
Type:  'a set ⇒ ??'a

The error(s) above occurred in typedef "mul_group"
```

Comment: I think that you are confusing `{x :: 'a set. x ≠ 0}` with `{x :: 'a. x ≠ 0} :: 'a set`: You want x to be an element of the field not a set of elements that are in the field.

Comment: The first assertion of lemma [Field_ZF_1_L4](https://isarmathlib.org/Field_ZF.html#a_Field_ZF_1_L4) in IsarMathLib shows the fact you want to prove. That is Isabelle/ZF but maybe it is possible to port the proof steps to Isabelle/HOL.